# How to implement Google AdMob mediation in Unity 5.3.5

Tags: android, admob, unity-game-engine, mobile-ad-mediation

I am very needy of help setting up AdMob as an ads provider for Unity, for an Android, and also using Admob mediation for receiving ads from other networks in-game.

I have "googled" for a loooong time, seriously. But I'm exhausted of finding no examples of unity projects, incomplete documentation, and people asking the same as me without any reply. I admit i'm a rookie in the subject, but i've followed all the steps I could infer in the more exact way I am able to do.

As far as I know, the steps are:

- Create an AdMob account.
- Create some other compatible ad networks accounts, and add their data into the AdMob account.
- Import the AdMob Unity plugin.
- Import each of the other ad networks "SDKs" and "adapters" into the Assets/Plugins folder (these files are .jar).
- Use the Admob Unity plugin in the application's specific code and enjoy ads from all networks.

But I can only receive AdMob ads, and I have not received a mere ad from another network. Looking at the "logcat" and the Charlie tools, it seems that the plugin does not request anything for a "non-AdMob" network.

I have some questions to ask:

- Is there any reference documentation or tutorial about ad mediation with unity 5?
- Are these steps described above the right way to do the mediation? Is a step missing?
- Do the SDK and the adapter need to be in the "Plugins" folder? Only one of them?
- Is a specific Unity plugin needed for each ad network, or the ".jar" files are enough?

I'd be very grateful if someone takes the time to read my issue and is willing to help. Moreover, this must be a common practice for developers, and a lot of them should know a lot about this mediation integration in Unity.

I'm really in need for help, because my job is depending on this. I'm willing to pay for help if it's necessary, through PayPal.

And please, this is something I have to implement by myself, any answer related to buying plugins won't help me at all. Sorry.

Thanks, best regards.

Comment: Any news on this. One of my questions is if I'm right... But I'm still not sure if I am...

Comment: I just find solution to your problem it too late but in future may be it can help someone.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/146265/google-admob-mediation-integration-for-unity/146268#146268

Answer (score 1):

Advertising in Unity games is an important way for Unity's game  to increase revenue. Commonly used ads include Google Admob, Inmobi,chartboost, Unity's unityads, etc. and the most used ones belong to Google Admob , so we're here with Google admob

Displaying ads in unity3d I chose to use Google and I heard that the fill rate is high and fair.

Admob contains 4 ads format: banner ads, screen ads, rewarded video ads, and native ads.

1. Download the Unity Admob plugin

Plugin URL https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob

2. Import the Unity Admob plugin into the Unity project

Import from Unity editor asset menu, pay attention to import all the content of the plugin, demo.cs and game asset is  example files, you can import or ignored them, if there is resource has the same name you should pay attention to the possibility of being covered

3. Add Admob  code to request and display ad

Open the script editor, add the script to call admob . After writing the script, drag the script to the main camera or other objects on the stage.

4. Example code for Interstitial ads in Unity

   Admob.Instance().initAdmob("banner id", "institial id"); //id is got from         apps.admob.com
   Admob.Instance().loadInterstitial();

This code initializes the ad parameters and request the ad to be loaded. The ad is not displayed immediately, so it is not visible and has no effect. To see the ad, you need to add the code that shows the ad.

```
If (Admob.Instance().isInterstitialReady()) {
      Admob.Instance().showInterstitial();
}else{
    Admob.Instance().loadInterstitial();
}
```

The timing for displaying advertisements is usually at the time of game clearance, successful login, or some other time that will not affect the user experience.

You can add a button when testing, click to show

5. Display rewarded video in Unity

Nowadays, video advertising and rewarded video advertisements are also common. Although the user experience is not so good and the filling is general, the unit price is relatively high, and sometimes it can be used to increase the income. Set Admob video parameters and load Admob video ad code

```
Admob.Instance().loadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
```

Just like the banner ads, you need to call display ads to see video ads

```
If (Admob.Instance().isRewardedVideoReady()) {
    Admob.Instance().showRewardedVideo();
}else{
    Admob.Instance().loadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313");
}
```

The timing of display is similar to Interstitial. The increase in revenue does not greatly affect user experience.

6. Add Google Admob native ads in Unity
   Native Ad is the most appropriate type of advertisement in app content. You can set the style of your own ads to achieve unity and harmonization with the overall product, common ads in the news list, ads in the game pictures etc.
   Admob had previously included 2 native ads, one called Express native and the other called Advanced native. Now that Express Native has been canceled, only advanced native ads is left.

This ad plugin is using Advanced Native Ad to implement a simple api showing native ad

```
Admob.Instance().showNativeBannerRelative(new AdSize(360,100), AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER, 0,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716");
```

Compared to Admob’s official api, this api is simplifies very much, only by defining the ad size, position, and parameters.

Of course, if you need to modify the style, you need to modify the style file inside the plugin, the ios xib file or the android's admoblib-release.aar\res\layout\ .

7. Implant Admob banner ads in Unity

Banner advertising is the most common and simplest advertisement. The click rate and unit price are relatively low, but the fill count is relatively large, the income is still good, and the user experience is also relatively good, without affecting the user operation. Embedding banner ad code

```
Admob.Instance().initAdmob("admob banner id", "admob interstitial id");//admob id with format ca-app-pub-279xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx
Admob.Instance().showBannerRelative(AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER, 0);
```

Very, very simple, just initialize the banner ad parameters, and then call the show, the ad will be displayed soon
The size and location of the advertisements are all defined by default. Just select one and it is very convenient.

Well, the presentation of Google Admob ads added to Unity games introduces a lot. Others like Unity Ads, Vungle, inmobi, chartboost, facebook ads  can directly been added with platform SDK and plugin adapters to the plugin library. Inside, using Admob as an ad mediation does not require extra code.

In general, a game with Admob plus one or two adapter ads is almost enough, too much will affect the performance and experience of the game